# python: how to get strings before decimal point?

Tags: python

I have a pandas data frame, df, which looks like this:

```
ENSGid              IB-7645        FB-AAPZ      FB-AAQ1      2J-AABH
ENSG00000242268.2   3593.368439    2147.028513  0            2586.98327
ENSG00000270112.3   0              0            104.0612396  89.73803605
ENSG00000167578.15  48710.20691    80149.55054  84261.08439  114534.9553
ENSG00000273842.1   0              0            0            0
ENSG00000078237.5   99587.29996    91523.92632  91066.1147   72151.84485
ENSG00000146083.10  247691.6483    350932.9484  254480.9342  374328.7091
```

How can I remove the decimal point and numbers after them so that the data frame looks like this:

```
    ENSGid              IB-7645        FB-AAPZ      FB-AAQ1      2J-AABH
    ENSG00000242268     3593.368439    2147.028513  0            2586.98327
    ENSG00000270112     0              0            104.0612396  89.73803605
    ENSG00000167578     48710.20691    80149.55054  84261.08439  114534.9553
    ENSG00000273842     0              0            0            0
    ENSG00000078237     99587.29996    91523.92632  91066.1147   72151.84485
    ENSG00000146083     247691.6483    350932.9484  254480.9342  374328.7091
```

I have read the pandas cookbook and searched answers in the stackoverflow, but all the answers are for float to integer but not for string.

All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split`

```
>>> df['ENSGid'] = df['ENSGid'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
'ENSG00000242268'
'ENSG00000270112'
...
```

Comment: this turns out to change all my ENSGid to be the "ENSG00000242268"

Comment: You need to do df['ENSGid'][0].split('.').str[0] instead.

Comment: @Rob run `df['ENSGid'][0].split('.').str[0]`  gives the error message: " 'list' object has no attribute 'str' "

Comment: Whoops, I meant `df['ENSGid'].str.split('.').str[0]`, but I see the answer has been changed in the meantime....

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lambda function to apply on each element with specified conditon

```
df['ENSGid'] = df['ENSGid'].apply(lambda x:x.split(".")[0] if "." in x)
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as @akash answer apart from the `if` which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your dataframe:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
               ENSGid        IB-7645        FB-AAPZ       FB-AAQ1  \
0   ENSG00000242268.2    3593.368439    2147.028513       0.00000
1   ENSG00000270112.3       0.000000       0.000000     104.06124
2  ENSG00000167578.15   48710.206910   80149.550540   84261.08439
3   ENSG00000273842.1       0.000000       0.000000       0.00000
4   ENSG00000078237.5   99587.299960   91523.926320   91066.11470
5  ENSG00000146083.10  247691.648300  350932.948400  254480.93420

         2J-AABH
0    2586.983270
1      89.738036
2  114534.955300
3       0.000000
4   72151.844850
5  374328.709100
```

Then you can use string methods by accessing the `.str` attribute in the data-frame object. The `str.replace` method accepts a regex-pattern:

```
In [11]: df['ENSGid'].str.replace(r'\.\d*','')
Out[11]:
0    ENSG00000242268
1    ENSG00000270112
2    ENSG00000167578
3    ENSG00000273842
4    ENSG00000078237
5    ENSG00000146083
Name: ENSGid, dtype: object
```

So, to substitute:

```
In [13]: df['ENSGid'] = df['ENSGid'].str.replace(r'\.\d*','')

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
            ENSGid        IB-7645        FB-AAPZ       FB-AAQ1        2J-AABH
0  ENSG00000242268    3593.368439    2147.028513       0.00000    2586.983270
1  ENSG00000270112       0.000000       0.000000     104.06124      89.738036
2  ENSG00000167578   48710.206910   80149.550540   84261.08439  114534.955300
3  ENSG00000273842       0.000000       0.000000       0.00000       0.000000
4  ENSG00000078237   99587.299960   91523.926320   91066.11470   72151.844850
5  ENSG00000146083  247691.648300  350932.948400  254480.93420  374328.709100
```

Answer (score 0):

All the following answers are correct,sorry for marked only one as correct.

```
1. df['ENSGid']=df['ENSGid'].str.split('.').str[0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
2. df['ENSGid'] = df['ENSGid'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
3. df['ENSGid'] = df['ENSGid'].str.replace(r'\.\d*','')
```

thank you, @juanpa.arrivillaga, @akash karothiya, @Rob, @Eliethesaiyan